# Is there a way to only delete letter out of an entry without deleting the entire entry?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am building an app that requires people to put numbers into entry boxes, I am using tkinter, on IDLE 3, and I was wondering if there is a way to make it so people can't put letters into the entry boxes? I want numbers to be the only thing able to be put into the text boxes.

Comment: If tkinter is anything like wxpython, there should be an event whenever the user edits the box.  Make that event handler check if there are any invalid characters

Answer (score -1):

**The best way is**, you can use `try/except` method. Try to convert user input using `int`, if no exception raised, then you're good to go (as you want only numbers). On the other hand if an exception is raised, do something else:

```py
# suppose the input is stored in the variable 'user_input'
try:
    int(user_input)
except ValueError:
    # do something else
```